# Export webpack function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

The `webpack` docs show the [type](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript) to be return from configuration [function](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function), but not the types of the parameters `env` and `argv`. Currently I've to type them as any, however what are the actual types of `env` and `argv`?

```
const configuration = (env: any, argv: any): Configuration => ({
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './foo.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'foo.bundle.js',
  },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both `any` because they are both coming from the webpack cli arguments, so it is not possible to know the type in advance at compile time (unless you strictly know that you will always pass certain arguments and ***force*** the type to be what you declare it to be)

[Webpack Environment Variables docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) may help to understand better.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find anything conclusive prior.